# Using dependency of dependency in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, dependencies, nuget, csproj

I'm trying to understand how dependencies work in .NET Core.

Let's say I have 2 projects. The **Project1** has this definition:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And this single class which uses the `Newtonsoft.Json` dependency:

```
public class Wizard
{
    public void DoMagic()
    {
        var settings = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it also references **Project2**, which has the following definition:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I remove the `Newtonsoft.Json` package reference from the **Project1**, I would expect it to no longer compile... But it does compile! As it seems, it's able to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` that is a dependency of **Project2**.

So I have 2 questions:

1. I've done my tests with an "internal" project reference for convenience, **but does this work the same way with external package references** (i.e. NuGet)?
2. **Can anybody explain the rationale here?** It seems risky to me, a change of a dependency in any of the dependencies of my project can break my project, if it is using that sub-dependency. In other words, **why is this allowed?** It seems to be always a bad idea to use implicitly a dependency of a dependency, because it could change and break your code, so why does the framework allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that's how it works across everything.
2. You can use `PrivateAssets` to control this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets